# Spring Boot REST not showing or linking to RESTController page/class

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-boot, web

I wrote this Spring Boot REST base application below, which starts the application but can not call or been link to the REST Controller page/class.

This is the main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class SoccerglueApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(SoccerglueApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

This is the controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/root")
public class SoccerNewsAPI {
 @GetMapping(value = "/in")
 public String getMessage() {
     return "Welcome to the Spring Boot Test";
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have in the same package this controller? If not you can create interface  and point of this package like this @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = [(DefaultCorePackage::class)])

Comment: Remove `@ComponentScan` from your SoccerglueApplication , as it is already defined in `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: I suspect you aren't following the Spring Boot best practices. I suspect your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in another (sub) package then your `@RestController`. The `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class will scan all packages and sub packages the class is defined in. So if the `@RestController` is in a package not covered by that it simply won't exist. The advice is to place the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a package that covers all sub packages.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the class level request mapping and it will work.

One more thing you can do is don't add any context base url like 'root' in class level request mapping, instead let it be like `@RequestMapping("/")` and add `server.servlet.context-path=/root` in application.properties file